# Devise: Tries to create a record without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, devise

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to create an app using devise for the authentication part. The first thing I noticed was that my tests were failing because my users fixtures hadn't an ID, so I put this on my `User` model

```
self.primary_key = :id
```

This helped my tests to run, but now I'm stuck on another problem. Everytime I try to add a user, the Devise controller fails with the following message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

SQLite3::ConstraintException: users.id may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "users" ("active", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "default_business_id", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Why isn't the User ID being created automatically? I'm running Devise 2 with Rails 3.2

Comment: Please show your authentification-related code.

Comment: Well, normally, setting the primary key is not something you should need to do. I would check my fixtures if I were you, you might find the problem there.

Comment: @Niels, this exception happens just when I create a real user in the frontend, the tests just run fine... anyway, I'll check the fixtures because you're right when you say that I shouldn't be setting the primary key

Comment: @Denis, I just have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the controllers that need authentication, this is all my authentication code right now... I haven't changed anything Devise-related

Comment: Look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/#test-helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally found what the problem was. The `users` table `id` column was not defined as a primary key in the DB, so that was the reason why Rails wasn't assigning a value to it automatically. I don't know how it happened, since I didn't touch the migration that creates this table (this file is generated by Devise). Anyway, making a complete rollback and executing the migrations again fixed the problem. Thanks all who replied and hope this serves anyone in the future.